# Prevent unification of variables within list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a predicate that returns 1 if a variable `X` and a predicate `f(X)` are both elements of an input list `L`, and 0 if at least one of them is missing.

This is what the predicate is supposed to do:

```
?- f_in_list([X, f(X)], Val).
  should return Val = 1

?- f_in_list([X, f(Y), Z], Val).
  should return Val = 0, as X and Y are different variables.
```

I have written this simple code:

```
f_in_list(L, 1) :-
    member(X, L),
    member(f(X), L),
    !.
f_in_list(_, 0).
```

My problem is that Prolog is always trying to unify the input variables, so it returns `X = f(X)` and `X = f(Y)`, respectively.
I tried to use `dif(X, f(X))` in order to circumvent this issue, but even that did not work. `Val` will always be 1 if the list contains at least two elements.

Is there a way to convert the variables to atoms or strings, so Prolog cannot unify the variables? Or even better, is there a way to prevent the unification of variables with the same name?

Comment: Since you had to detect only `X` and `f(X)`, you can write them as `x` and `f(x)`. Then you can provide a list like this `[x, f(x), z]` (using constants instead of variables).

Comment: Sadly I cannot do that, as the program requires a specific kind of input. If there was a way to assign pairwise distinct constants to my input variables automatically, this would work.

Comment: In what way did you attempt to use `dif/2`? I would be interested in seeing that attempted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an good use of `==/2`. This operator does not *unify* but it checks if its arguments are the same. Here is a little bit of `==/2` behavior:

```
2 ?- X == X
|    .
true.

3 ?- X == Y.
false.

4 ?- X = Y, Z = Y, X == Z, write('yes'), nl.
yes
X = Y, Y = Z.

5 ?- X = Y, Z = W, X == Z.
false.

6 ?-
```

We can use this to create a non-unifying `nu_member/2` predicate:

```
nu_member(X, [Y|_]) :- X == Y.
nu_member(X, [_|T]) :- nu_member(X, T).
```

And we an use this in `f_in_list/2`:

```
f_in_list(L, 1) :-
    member(X, L),
    nu_member(f(X), L),
    !.
f_in_list(_, 0).
```

Which results in:

```
2 ?- f_in_list([X,f(X), Z], B).
B = 1.

3 ?- f_in_list([X,f(Y), Z], B).
B = 0.

4 ?- f_in_list([X,f(Y), f(Z)], B).
B = 0.

5 ?- f_in_list([X,f(Y), f(Z),Z], B).
B = 1.
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't expect such a simple solution. Great work!

Answer (score 2):

As referred by @lurker you should consider using `==/2` since it succeeds only if the two terms are already identical without further unification.

Her is my implementation:

```
f_in_list(L, 1) :-
    member(X, L),
    member(f(Y), L),
    X == Y ,!.

f_in_list(_, 0).
```

Example:

```
?- f_in_list([X, f(X)], Val).
Val = 1.

?- f_in_list([X, f(Y), Z], Val).
Val = 0.
```

Comment: You can use `X \== f(Y)` and avoid the `\+`. :)

Comment: Do you need `X \== f(X)`? I'm not where I can try it myself, but I think that expression might always be true.

Comment: I now like your answer better than mine. :)